# Laravel 5.3 uploading to Amazonaws error

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to upload picture to my amazonaws `s3`, but when I submit the upload I get this error:

> Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/*********/1476203786.jpg"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/********/1476203786.jpg` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:
>   
>   `SignatureDoesNotMatch`The request signature we calcul (truncated...)
>   SignatureDoesNotMatch (client): The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. - 
>   `SignatureDoesNotMatch`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.AKIAJTRQJVWCHLVZY2PAAWS4-HMAC-SHA256
>   20161011T163628Z
>   20161011/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request

I've tried changing the region but nothing helps.

This is code for uploading my image:

```
$s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
$filePath = $imageFileName;
$s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($image), 'public');
```

Comment: Check the time on your server. If your server's time is inaccurate by more than a couple minutes, this can occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you get `SignatureDoesNotMatch` exception, it's likely your credentials are incorrect. I'd recommend you double check your key-pair generated through your AWS Console.